# $\mathbb F_q$-linear polynomials in several variables

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $K$ be a infinite field of characteristic $p>0$ and $q$ be a power of $p$. Let $P$ be a polynomial of $K[X,Y]$ that is $\mathbb F_q$-linear, that is
$$P\left(\left(\begin{array}{l}x_0\\y_0\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{l}x_1\\y_1\end{array}\right)\right)=P\left(\left(\begin{array}{l}x_0\\y_0\end{array}\right)\right)+P\left(\left(\begin{array}{l}x_0\\y_0\end{array}\right)\right)$$ for all $x_0,y_0,x_1,y_1\in K^4$ and $$P\left(\xi\left(\begin{array}{l}x_0\\y_0\end{array}\right)\right)=\xi P\left(\left(\begin{array}{l}x_0\\y_0\end{array}\right)\right)$$for every $\xi\in\mathbb F_q$. I want to prove that $P(X,Y)=Q_1(X)+Q_2(Y)$ where $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are $\mathbb F_q$-linear polynomials in one variable. But I did not manage to prove it. Any help would be welcome

Comment: $P(x,y)=P (x,0)+P (0,y) $?